# How to create a JavaScript constructor that returns a custom string to Object.prototype.toString()?

Tags: javascript

A little JavaScript puzzle for you kind wizards:

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

var e = new Error();
console.log(toString.call(e));  // '[object Error]'

function Poodle(){}
var fido = new Poodle();
console.log(toString.call(fido)); // '[object Object]'
```

How do I make the last line return `'[object Poodle]'`?

Comment: If you just want the get the name you could do this `fido.constructor.name //=> Poodle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part of that string is the internal [*[[class]]*](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2) as [defined](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2) in the ECMAScript specification.

You could of course define your own `toString()` on the object, but that won't be affected by calling `Object.prototype.toString()` on it and setting the custom context.

You could overwrite `Object.prototype.toString()`, but that is very nasty and you shouldn't do it.

Basically, without compiling your own ECMAScript and making a custom `[[class]]`, you can't do it.

You shouldn't be relying on that string to determine information about a custom object you've created. You can use the [`instanceof`](http://jsfiddle.net/2AkTG/) operator or the [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) property.